# JUnit equivalents for TestNG's @BeforeSuite, @BeforeTest

Tags: junit, refactoring, testng, test-suite

I'm refactoring some test classes [from TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121114/testng-fails-to-load-test-classes-from-ant) to JUnit 4. During the process, I've stumbled upon the following annotations:

```
@BeforeTest
@AfterTest
```

According to the manual:

> The annotated method will be run before/after any test method belonging to the classes inside the  tag is run.

What would be the [equivalent annotations](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-vs-testng-comparison/) in JUnit?

Comment: What do the annotations do in TestNG? And JUnit has Suites.

Comment: After following the link you provided I'm no longer sure my answer is correct. What is the difference between Before/AfterMethod and Before/AfterTest in TestNG?

Comment: Not quite sure, that's why I asked. I think there is a subtle difference that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the original answer, but I think it is wrong. See below for a better one**

The equivalent would be the annotations

```
@Before
```

and

```
@After
```

see also http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html

**This is a better answer, after I learned about the difference between Before/AfterMethod and Before/AfterTest in TestNG**

If I got it right, with Before/AfterTest you can run a method before or after a list of tests, that you specify inside the annotation or a separate document.

There is no out of the box feature like this in JUnit.

Probably the best you can do, is put what ever you want to do in a [JUnit Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules). See also http://schauderhaft.de/2011/07/24/rules-in-junit-4-9-beta-3/

Then you can use that Rule in any test that needs it.